# Scanner issue! Code is skipping the first user input and printing twice instead of once ONLY on the first iteration

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop, output

https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse142/15sp/homework/6/spec.pdf

EDIT* Input Files are here:(sorry i'm new to stack overflow, hopefully this works)

I've also tried console.next() but it gives different errors than console.nextLine() in the rePlaceholder method. **

tarzan.txt - https://pastebin.com/XDxnXYsM

output for tarzan should look like this: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse142/17au/homework/madlibs/expected_output_1.txt

simple.txt https://pastebin.com/Djc2R0Vz

clothes.txt https://pastebin.com/SQB8Q7Y8

this code should print to an output file you name.

Hello, I have a question about scanners because I don't understand why the code
is skipping the user input on the first iteration but works fine on the rest.
I'm writing a code to create a madlib program and the link will provide the explanation to the program but pretty much you have these placeholders in a text file and when you see one, you prompt for user input to replace it with your own words. However, my program always go through TWO placeholders first and only ask the user input for one, completely skipping the first placeholder. What is wrong with my code??? Also, how do you fix this? Everything else is running perfectly fine, only that the first line is consuming two placeholders so I'm always off by one.

Welcome to the game of Mad Libs.
I will ask you to provide various words

and phrases to fill in a story.

The result will be written to an output file.

(C)reate mad-lib, (V)iew mad-lib, (Q)uit? c

Input file name: tarzan.txt

Output file name: test.txt

**Please type an adjective: Please type a plural noun: DD DDDD** <--- why is it like this

Please type a noun: DDDD

Please type an adjective: DD

Please type a place:

---

---

========================================================================

```
package MadLibs;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MadLibs2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      intro();
      boolean isTrue = true;
      while(isTrue) {
          System.out.print("(C)reate mad-lib, (V)iew mad-lib, (Q)uit? ");
          String choice = console.next();
         if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
            create(console);
         } 
         else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("v")) {
            view(console);
         } 
         else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            System.exit(0);
         }  
      }
   }

   public static void view(Scanner console) throws FileNotFoundException {
       System.out.print("Input file name: ");
       String viewFile = console.next();
       File existingMadLib = new File(viewFile);
       Scanner printText = new Scanner(existingMadLib);
       while(printText.hasNextLine()) {
           System.out.println(printText.nextLine());
       }
   }

   public static void create(Scanner console) throws FileNotFoundException {
      System.out.print("Input file name: ");
      String inputFile = console.next();
      File newMadLib = new File(inputFile);
      while(!newMadLib.exists()) {
         System.out.print("File not found. Try again: ");
         inputFile = console.next();
         newMadLib = new File(inputFile);
      }
      System.out.print("Output file name: ");
      String outputFile = console.next();
      System.out.println();
      PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File(outputFile));
      Scanner input = new Scanner(newMadLib); 
      while(input.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = input.nextLine();
         outputLines(line, output, console);
      }
   }

   public static void outputLines(String line, PrintStream output, Scanner console) throws FileNotFoundException{
      String s = "";
      Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
      while(lineScan.hasNext()){
         s = lineScan.next();
         if(s.startsWith("<") || s.endsWith(">")) {
            s = rePlaceholder(console, lineScan, s);
         }
         output.print(s + " ");
      }
      output.println();
   }

   public static String rePlaceholder(Scanner console, Scanner input, String token) {           
      String placeholder = token;
      placeholder = placeholder.replace("<", "").replace(">", "").replace("-",  " ");
      if (placeholder.startsWith("a") || placeholder.startsWith("e") || placeholder.startsWith("i") 
       || placeholder.startsWith("o") || placeholder.startsWith("u")) {
         System.out.print("Please type an " + placeholder + ": ");
      }  else {
          System.out.print("Please type a " + placeholder + ": ");
       }
      String change = console.nextLine();
      return change;
   }

   public static void intro() {
      System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Mad Libs.");
      System.out.println("I will ask you to provide various words");
      System.out.println("and phrases to fill in a story.");
      System.out.println("The result will be written to an output file.");
   }
}
```

Comment: Add input and output files examples please.

Answer (score 0):

in your `rePlaceholder`, change this line:

```
String change = console.nextLine();
```

Into this

```
String change = console.next();
```

Your problem is that nextLine doesn't wait for your output, just reads what it has in the console, waiting for a new line.

This is from the documentation to be a bit more precise on the explanation:

> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a
>   line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line
>   to skip if no line separators are present.

**UPDATE**

After reading the comment, the previous solution will not work for multiple words.
After reading the output file, you are using `next()`.
You need to make another call to `nextLine()` to clean the buffer of any newlines.

```
 System.out.print("Output file name: ");
 String outputFile = console.next();
 console.nextLine(); // dummy call
 System.out.println();
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried console.next() but then when I need to insert more than one word as an answer (for example: please type a noun: hello world), my code prints the prompt n times based on how many words I have, which in this case is 2.

Please type an adjective: Hello World Im

Please type a plural noun: Please type a noun: Please type an adjective:

Comment: @vee updated my answer. Tried it locally, seems to be fine with multiple words